# Raspberry Pi 3 Wi-Fi power drops after 1 minute

Tags: wifi

I am running Raspbian Jessie (the latest one in the time of posting this) and Wi-Fi drops after exactly 1 minute. And it doesn't matter if its idle or not: even when I'm pinging my Pi, it drops after a minute. My PSU is 2 amps, which is more than enough for the Raspberry Pi 3 AFAIK. When I ran the following commands, the Pi was connected to the router through an Ethernet cable, so if any info is insufficient in the logs feel free to ask in the comments.

Here's the output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    post-up iw dev $IFACE set power_save off
    wireless-power off
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

wireless-power off

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Output of `sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog`:

```
ct 30 18:02:40 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: Listen normally on 9 wlan0 192.168.1.43 UDP 123
Oct 30 18:02:40 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: peers refreshed
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[549]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b2:46:fc:61:ac:c0 reason=0 locally_generated=1
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Sun Oct 30 18:04:04 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: wlan0: carrier lost
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[549]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583749] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583787] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583796] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583807] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583822] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583835] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583847] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583862] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583876] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583889] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583903] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi kernel: [  199.583915] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::608e:ea7f:768f:804b
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::608e:ea7f:768f:804b on wlan0.
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::608e:ea7f:768f:804b.
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: wlan0: deleting route to 192.168.1.0/24
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.1.1
Oct 30 18:03:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.43 on wlan0.
Oct 30 18:03:36 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: Deleting interface #9 wlan0, 192.168.1.43#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=56 secs
Oct 30 18:03:36 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: peers refreshed
Oct 30 18:08:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: carrier acquired
Oct 30 18:08:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: adding address fe80::52eb:a8b3:d525:be90
Oct 30 18:08:22 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Sun Oct 30 18:08:52 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Oct 30 18:08:22 raspberrypi kernel: [  488.150302] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC1E1
Oct 30 18:08:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: IAID eb:ee:01:5f
Oct 30 18:08:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.64
Oct 30 18:08:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Oct 30 18:08:24 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::52eb:a8b3:d525:be90.
Oct 30 18:08:24 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 30 18:08:24 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Registering new address record for fe80::52eb:a8b3:d525:be90 on eth0.*.
Oct 30 18:08:26 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: Listen normally on 10 eth0 fe80::52eb:a8b3:d525:be90 UDP 123
Oct 30 18:08:26 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: peers refreshed
Oct 30 18:08:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: leased 192.168.1.64 for 86400 seconds
Oct 30 18:08:28 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.64.
Oct 30 18:08:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Oct 30 18:08:28 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 30 18:08:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
Oct 30 18:08:28 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[425]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.64 on eth0.IPv4.
Oct 30 18:08:29 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: Listen normally on 11 eth0 192.168.1.64 UDP 123
Oct 30 18:08:29 raspberrypi ntpd[572]: peers refreshed
Oct 30 18:08:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Session c3 of user pi.
Oct 30 18:08:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user pi.
Oct 30 18:08:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[432]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

As far as I see everything in this file is related to networking.

As you can see I modified 2 lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but they still don't help.

I am not using any Wi-Fi dongle, it's the Pi 3's built-in Wi-Fi thing.

Comment: Does it do the same thing with Ethernet?

Comment: @sir_ian Nope, ethernet works fine

Comment: The red PWR led does not flicker at all during this time period?

Comment: I never actually paid attention to that, give me a sec.

Comment: @goldilocks nope, its on and doesn't flicker at all

Comment: If you have other access to the Pi have a look at `sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog` after the wifi goes down and post that if anything is obviously related to wifi or networking.  If you don't, you can still look back though that file for the appropriate time period (which is easy enough if the time has been set correctly at that point, but awkward otherwise).

Comment: @goldilocks edited the question, (i had access to the pi through monitor and keyboard + ssh through ethernet and router) and there's the output. sorry for the long text out there.

Comment: You certainly aren't getting the `.152` static ip.  You may want to double check how you are doing this here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/5538

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47674/discussion-between-areg-hovhannisyan-and-goldilocks).

Comment: It may not be causing your problem, but having non-standard config files is NOT going to help. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
Raspbian no longer uses the traditional Debian networking.

Comment: ok so today I will try to configure mt static ip with the instructions you gave and tell you what happened

Comment: Ok Im really late, but no success. But!
I Swear it used to work a couple of hours ago! I don't know how, but it worked. I re-burnt the raspbian image on the microsd card,update the kernel (rpi-update), but still, it doesn't help! (I did all that stuff before it stopped working.)

Comment: Did you found any solution? I'm also having a same problem here...

Comment: Nope. Still no. I think my power supply/usb cord might be to blame, but changing them didn't help. I'll probably have an answer after Christmas

Comment: Have the same issue. Wifi disconnects after 1 min. Doesn't matter if password and encryption on the AP are set or not. My router hardware is somewhat old. I can use that Wi-Fi just fine with other devices. When I set a password, RPi3 asks me every time to put in the password again, even though it's stored in plaintext in the `wpa_supplicant.conf`. After logging in maybe 20 times the message "wlan0: Disassociated from {SSID}" shows when hovering over the Wi-Fi symbol in the task bar and my network is no longer available in the list. Here is the strange thing: it works fine when I make an AP wit

Comment: I don't really know what happened, but it works now. Didn't change anything. All I did was turning my Pi on just like any other time. This is the weirdest thing I've ever seen in my life.

Comment: ...h the Android phone and share the 4gdata. (someone cut the comment off at the character limit.) I've ordered a wifi USB dongle and will test if that works better than the built in.

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. I have no idea whats wrong. Changed Power supplies, usb cables.. Just doesn't want to work! It is not stable. It works sometimes but then drops. If it drops it means it's gonna drop next time too. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=146418

Comment: this line "raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[549]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid reason=0 locally_generated=1" seems to try to tell you what is going on. It looks like it's not the device itself, but the router. the internetz seems to agree that you should attempt to switch the channel your wifi router is using.

Comment: Switching the channel does seem to help. I am still keeping track of things, because I'm not 100% sure that this is solved forever. Will keep you guys updated. You helped me so much. I love this community.

Comment: Ok just a quick update It seems like whenever my router put the wifi channel to 13 the wifi started dropping. No idea why though.